# Error for before insert or update on

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, database-trigger

I am a new to queries in dbms, so If someone could figure out what should be done here. Also, I am using Mysql.

code:

```
-> create trigger age_trigger before insert or update of age on employee
-> for each row
-> when( new.age <25)
-> begin
-> select 'Age can not be less than 25'
-> end;
```

error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'or update of age on employee for each row when(
>   new.age <25) begin select 'Age c' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below can be one of the option to implement `BEFORE INSERT` to obtain your desired result.

```
CREATE TRIGGER age_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.age < 25 
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Age can not be less than 25'; 
END IF; 
END;
```

Similar syntax can be used for `before update` trigger.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RCBDCJ71007)**

Answer (score 1):

You can't just come up with your own syntax :)

Have a look at the manual: [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

You can't specify multiple trigger_events. You need separate insert and update triggers. And this `of age` also has no business there.

All in all, what you're trying to do there can be done in MySQL (google for SIGNAL, if you insist), but best practice is, that this sort of logic is placed in the application layer. Don't put such logic in the database.

Comment: okay, I did make that change but now the error is coming in when clause. Can you guess that.

Comment: Do you see a `WHEN` in the link I posted? And I really urge you to put such logic in your application. And there are plenty of examples for writing triggers in the manual as well as the SIGNAL page, that I suggested to google for. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. When you ask a question, you should have at least a clue about the topic. No offense, but you don't seem to have that. Consult a tutorial or something...

Comment: Sorry, but your advice was of no use to me.

Comment: Well, sorry to hear that. Often I follow the words "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day, teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". That involves, that the man/woman does some work on his/her own.

Comment: Oh, that's great! Nice name tho XD

Comment: You're making fun of other people's name? Okay then, teenie.